# Unable to login to Stack Exchange iOS application

Tags: bug, status-completed, ios-app

I am being unable to log in to the Stack Exchange application on my iPhone 4S running iOS 8.1.

I am trying to log in using the Stack Exchange option but get the following:

> 'key' is not valid for passed
>   'access_token', token not found.

The app is version 1.2, the latest available.

This weird error is showing up each time I try to log in.

> [image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE: This change appears in version 1.2.1 which is propagating through the App Store.**

This will be fixed in the next release. The app didn't have a proper recovery mechanism when it got in an invalid state. Now it will always create clean requests from the login screen.

An interim solution is to delete and reinstall the app. :/

Comment: Looks like [it's back](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244333/error-while-trying-to-log-in-stackexchange-ios-app).