# Error while trying to log into Stack Exchange iOS app

Tags: bug, status-completed, login, ios-app

When using my Stack Exchange account to log in to the Stack Exchange iOS app I get an error alert:

> Error 
>   `key` is not valis for passed  
>   `acces_token`, token not found.

I am confident I am using the correct email and password.

Can anyone relate to this problem?

Comment: This [was fixed a while ago](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243323/unable-to-login-to-stack-exchange-ios-application) and probably returned. Can you try to delete and reinstall the app?

Comment: @ShadowWizard OK, thanks! Now I know it's not only me having this issue :)

Comment: Yeah, this is some comfort... :)

Comment: Version 1.2.1 is on its way to the app store fixing this.